# 'Angular5' Service (rxjs/observable) two components rendering issue

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular5

I have a master list app with two component: `usersList` and `usersMap` both of which, are holding a `private users` variable, that gets its data from 
 the service.

Both are subscribed to a `users-service` that has a `Users array` with `users data`.

Every change on this array will cause both components to render and update their users variable.

[Photo of the app on runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e3PN.png)

When I create a new user, the `users array` gets updated,  and the `usersList` gets re-rendered,
but the usersMap isn`t.

I tried some solutions provided on stack, but they didn't work.
for example: [Angular2 Observable BehaviorSubject service not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083756/angular2-observable-behaviorsubject-service-not-working)

A link to the github: https://github.com/TomerOmri/angular-users-map/tree/master/test-app/src/app

- **`UserList` component:** 
  https://github.com/TomerOmri/angular-users-map/blob/master/test-app/src/app/userlist/userlist.component.ts
- **`UserMap` component:** https://github.com/TomerOmri/angular-users-map/blob/master/test-app/src/app/usersmap/usersmap.component.ts
- **`User` Service:**

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
    import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
    import { User } from "./user";
    import { USERS } from "./users-mock";
    
    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {
      constructor() { }
      getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        var userList = of(USERS);
        return userList;
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Please add how are you updating the source array to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code to do your task:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private userList = USERS;
  public users = new BehaviourSubject<any>(userList);
  constructor() { }

  addUser(user): {
    this.userList.push(user);
    this.users.next(this.userList);
  }
```

Now use this users property in your both component to get data. When you need to add just call addUser method of service.
Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks! what is 'BehaviourSubject'? the class doesn`t know it. and the function I need is "get Users" not to add, how should I do it?